# How do I access a property of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code

**CODE JS:**

```
this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {

    // from backend a response will be returned for every file uploaded
    var responseSuccess = [];
    $.each(responseText, function( index, value ) {
        responseSuccess.push(value.success );
        console.log(responseText["message: "+value.message ]);  //here
    });
});
```

The object has the following form ... I put a picture more clearly understand

[image]

I want to put in console the following message

```
"Sorry,there was an error uploading your file"
```

What is the correct way to access the properties?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused between the message and string concatenation. You should use:

```
console.log(responseText["message"] + value.message);
```

Now the funny part is, both the `responseText["message"]` and `value.message` has the same value, as you are iterating `responseText` here. So you either need:

```
console.log(responseText[0]["message"]); // OR
console.log(value.message);
```

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks buddy. `:)`

Comment: the first option does not work ... somehow know why?

Comment: @D.Cristi Ah yea! It is because, you need to loop. `responseText[0]["message"]` should work. Doesn't it? Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @D.Cristi Thanks buddy! `:)`